# Extract first element from Nested Array in JSON NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I'm trying to grab the nested array called platforms, but i only want the first key in there. So for the Array it should be like `[{platforms: [windows], [windows]]}` instead of `[{platforms: [windows, osx, linux, null], [windows, null, null, null]]}`  Is this even achievable? I looked through `.map` and `.filter` but can't seem to just grab the first piece of the array.

**Example ARRAY**

```
[{ id: 1,
game: { position: 1},
platforms: [ 'windows', 'osx', 'linux', null ],
title: 'xxx',
user: {
  url: 'xxxx',
  name: 'xxx',
  id: 1
}
},{ id: 2,
game: { position: 2},
platforms: [ 'windows', null, null, null, ],
title: 'xxx',
user: {
  url: 'xxxx',
  name: 'xxx',
  id: 2
}
]
```

How can I handle this in Javascript / NodeJS

```
var result = body.games.filter(a=>a).reduce((acc, a) => {
    return acc.concat(a)
}, []).map(a=>a.platforms);
console.log(result);
```

Result =
`[ 'windows', 'osx', 'linux' null ],  [ 'windows', null, null, null ],`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `.map` should do this:

```js
function mapPlatform(data) {
  return data.map(entry => Array.isArray(entry.platforms) ? entry.platforms[0] : 'no platform data available')
}

const data = [{id:1,game:{position:1},platforms:['windows','osx','linux',null],title:'xxx',user:{url:'xxxx',name:'xxx',id:1,},},{id:2,game:{position:2},platforms:['windows',null,null,null],title:'xxx',user:{url:'xxxx',name:'xxx',id:2,},}];
console.log(mapPlatform(data));
```

Comment: frustrating! I've done this before and i get TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined. However using your `data` const it works. There must be something wrong with my json output that i'm trying to pull from.

Comment: `console.log(body.games.map(entry => entry.platforms));` gives me
`[
  [ 'windows', 'osx', 'linux' ],
  [ 'windows', 'osx', 'linux' ],
]`
But if i do platforms[0] i get undefined..

Comment: Well, the one you've added to the question is invalid, yes. It is missing a `}` before `]`.

Comment: ok any idea on how to append that to my json to make it valid? I'll mark your answer as correct regardless, as you are right!

Comment: It would be preferable to make sure that the json is valid in the first place, instead of manually fixing it - where are you reading the data from?

Comment: yeah i can't change the data src. here is an example of one of the ones i'm parsing https://itch.io/bundle/500/games.json

Comment: Turns out the data does not always contain a platform-array, I'll edit my answer. It will now add "no platform data available" if the array is empty/does not exist (you can change this as you like ofc) :)